# Highchart parameter from a hidden element doesnt works

Tags: jquery

In my highchart ,
           series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [ 
             ['INDIVIDUAL - LEFT',  30],
            ]
        }]  this code works fine for me.If I take the parameters from a hidden element like,

series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [ 
            $('#graph').val()
            ]
        }]   it doesnt work for me.Please suggest if anybody knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing that into an array first OR a variable if you can.

EG:

```
var forMyGraph = $('#graph').val();
```

Then plug that into your graph just like that

```
 [{ 
type: 'pie', 
name: 'Browser share', 
data: [ forMyGraph ] 
}]
```

**EDIT:** Some snippets from my jQuery passing to Highchart:

**Step 1:** I create a new Array for both values I want, both the name of the slice and the value for that slice

```
var Titles = new Array();
var Totals = new Array();
```

**Step 2:** I then use jQuery to go through my hidden table to grab my values and push them into my array:

```
$("#GridView2 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
                    var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
                    Titles.push(cell.html());
                    // it receives something like "Title1, Title2, Title3"

                });

        $("#GridView2 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
            var cell2 = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
            var scell2 = cell2.text();
            var sscell2 = scell2.split(/[a-zA-Z,\s]/).join("").slice(0, -2);
            Totals.push(sscell2);

            // don't worry about the splitting and slicing, I needed to use Regex to remove some stuff
```

**STEP 3:** I then set my different titles:

```
//I do this by selecting my items out of the array I built
            Title1 = Titles[0];
            Title2 = Titles[1];
            Title3 = Titles[2];
            Title4 = Titles[3];
            Title5 = Titles[4];
            Title6 = Titles[5];
```

And my different totals:

```
        //Back to Int for Graphs, notice how I now parseInt() here, Highcharts are very fussy
        Total1 = parseInt(Totals[0]);
        Total2 = parseInt(Totals[1]);
        Total3 = parseInt(Totals[2]);
        Total4 = parseInt(Totals[3]);
        Total5 = parseInt(Totals[4]);
        Total6 = parseInt(Totals[5]);
```

**Then finally**, like you have done, I plugged the data into my graph:

```
series: [{
                        name: 'Total',
                        data: [
                [Title1, Total1],
                [Title2, Total2],
                {
                    name: Title3,
                    y: Total3,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                [Title4, Total4],
                [Title5, Total5],
                [Title6, Total6]
                ]
                    }, ]
```

I hope this helps you :) Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I have tried with the same but still graph not showing

Comment: Hi Preet, not to worry - we will help you out. Highcharts are a pain in the arse sometimes! I also deal with them :) lol... Okay, first things first. Would it be too much trouble for you to pass those separately? have a look at what I did for one of my graphs (Check the updated answer)

Comment: I am populating the graph with a kind of survey result and the result I am not saving on db.So I am keeping the result in a hidden element and passing it as graph parameter on final stage.Do you have any idea to pass this parameters separately rather than keeping it on hidden element